# How do I make a HTTP POST request to an url from within a c++ dll?

Tags: php, c++, http, dll, post

there's an open-source application I need to use. It allows you to use a custom dll. Unfortunately, I can't code c++; i don't like it; it don't want to learn it.

I do know PHP very well however, thus you can see that I'll rather do my logic within a PHP application. Thus I'm thinking about posting the data from c++/dll to a url on my localhost. (i have my local server set up, that's not the problem).

I need to post a large amount of variables (thus a POST and not GET request required). The return value will only be one (int)variable, either 0, 1 or 2.

So I need a c++ function that:
1) will post variables to an url.
2) Wait for, and receive the answer.

The data type can be in xml, soap, json, whatever, doesn't matter. Is there anyone that can write a little c++ http function for me?

pretty please? ;)

Comment: You want someone to write code for you? Sounds like a job for elancer or rentacoder.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is "do my job for me" question, no matter of the job. "Wash my dishes cause I don't like it and want to do it myself" is the same.

Comment: Not a programming question. Saying you can't be bothered to put the time into something and then begging someone else to do it for you isn't likely to score you too many favours around here with people who value effort.

Answer (score 2):

Someone's already done this: libcurl.dll